# In Python, how to implement a min-priority queue which maintains the heap invariant when you change the priority of one of its members?

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, observers

I'd like to implement Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm using a heap data structure. To this end, I'm looking for a heap which automatically sifts its members up and down as required when you change the priority of an element.

So far I've tried [queue.PriorityQueue](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) and Stutzbach's [heapdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HeapDict), but neither seems to have this property as seen from the tests below:

```
import queue
from heapdict import heapdict
import pytest

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.d < other.d


def test_priority_queue():
    node1 = Node(d=5)
    node2 = Node(d=10)
    Q = queue.PriorityQueue()
    Q.put(node1)
    Q.put(node2)
    node2.d = 2
    assert Q.get().d == 2       # Fails because 5 != 2

def test_heapdict():
    node1 = Node(d=5)
    node2 = Node(d=10)
    hd = heapdict()
    hd[1] = node1
    hd[2] = node2
    node2.d = 2
    index, node = hd.popitem()
    assert node.d == 2          # Fails because 5 != 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

When I update the priority of `node2` to `2` instead of `10`, it should automatically move to the top of the heap, so that the `get`/`popitem` method returns it. I'd like to create a data structure such that a similar test would pass.

I'm struggling a bit to come up with a high-level idea of how to implement this, however. It should probably follow an [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and use a [property](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property) attribute, but how exactly?

**Update**

An object that does something similar is [pqdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pqdict/). However, according to [its documentation](http://pqdict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#what-is-an-indexed-priority-queue) it also doesn't work with mutable objects:

> **Value mutability**. If you use mutable objects as values in a `pqdict`, changes to the state of those objects can break the priority queue. If this does happen, the data structure can be repaired by calling `pq.heapify()`. (But you probably shouldn’t be using mutable values in the first place.)

Comment: Simply changing an attribute of your `Node` cannot possibly trigger reordering of your heap - no code is being called in response to this change.  You'd need to make `d` an actual property with a setter that tells the containing heap about the change.  It is possible to reposition a changed item within a heap, but I'm pretty sure it would be an O(log n) operation, not fundamentally more efficient than simply deleting it and reinserting it with the new value.

Comment: Does https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html meet your needs? Also, if you want to re-prioritize an item, pop it and re-add it, as @jasonharper said. It's slightly more expensive (asymptotically equivalent cost), but much less code. That is, unless this is an academic exercise, in which case I'd implement everything from the ground up starting with nothing fancier than a list.